Error "Cannot resolve symbol 'usuario'" al usar JPA y Hibernate en Spring Boot
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Spring Boot donde estoy utilizando JPA y Hibernate para acceder a una base de datos MySQL. Tengo una clase usuario que está correctamente mapeada a una tabla en la base de datos, pero estoy teniendo problemas al intentar utilizarla en mi clase DAO.
Mi clase usuario se ve así:
    package com.curso.curso.models;

    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "usuarios")
    public class usuario {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private Long id;

        private String nombre;
        private String apellido;
        private String edad;
        private String email;
        private String telefono;

        // Constructores, getters y setters
    }


Y mi clase DAO usuarioDaoImp tiene el método para obtener la lista de usuarios:
    package com.curso.curso.Dao;

    import com.curso.curso.models.usuario;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import java.util.List;

    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class usuarioDaoImp implements usuarioDao {

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        @Override
        public List<usuario> getUsuarios() {
            String query = "FROM usuario"; // Aquí "usuario" es el nombre de la clase, no de la tabla
            return entityManager.createQuery(query, usuario.class).getResultList();
        }
    }

Sin embargo, estoy recibiendo el error "Cannot resolve symbol 'usuario'" en la línea que hace referencia a la clase usuario en mi consulta JPQL FROM usuario. Además, estoy obteniendo la advertencia "Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.List' to 'java.util.List<com.curso.curso.models.usuario>'" en el método getUsuarios().
He verificado que la clase usuario está en el paquete correcto y está importada correctamente en mi clase DAO. ¿Qué podría estar causando estos errores y cómo puedo resolverlos?
¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Es facil desde el servicio llama a usuaridioDAO.findall y eso ya te devuelve una lista. tu error esta en el uso de esa query que le saltarria la parte de select.
ademas no necesitas tener una implementacion del repo.

La tabla la llamas Table(name = "usuarios") y en la consulta haces referencia a "usuario"
String query = "FROM usuario";
prueba a poner usuarios

Es una consulta de JPQL no de SQL. Ahí debe aparecer un nombre de una clase etiquetada como Entity; es decir, la sustitución que planteas no resuelve el problema.
